# "I look forward" or "I'm looking forward"?

Tags: tense, verb-forms, phrasal-verbs

Which should I say:

> I'm looking forward to our meeting.

or

> I look forward to our meeting.

Answer (score 12):

These are both correct. I would add, though, that *I'm looking forward to our meeting* sounds (to me, at least) more conversational (and a bit more genuine), whereas *I look forward to our meeting* is a bit more formal/polite. I would expect to find the *I'm looking* form in spoken language, and the *I look* form in writing (likely at the end of an email confirming a meeting).

Comment: This is the correct distinction (such as it is). Using present continuous invites the reader/audience to be more aware of the writer/speaker's *current emotional state*, which can make it significantly more appropriate in personal/informal/friendly contexts. The standard simple present (which can also be *future*) is more suitable in an office context, for example.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say that it's six of one and half a dozen of the other. But I always use "**I look forward to...**". Just my personal preference: it's shorter.

Comment: With "six of one and half a dozen of the other" your answer opens a new question to me :).

Comment: @Michael Härtl: What's the new question?

Comment: Nevermind, i've just looked it up in an online dictionary. I was confused to which "one" and "other" you are referring. But i learned that it's just a saying.

Comment: As could "nevermind". I had to check if it was an acceptable contraction. It is funny something that makes so much sense in our heads can be misunderstood by others so easily.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking forward to our meeting with verification with email. All email and invoices need to be direct verification an right business formatting instead of not useful data information on them.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.