# In formal writing, what are alternatives forms of "I look forward to talking/hearing with/from you"?

Tags: phrase-request, expressions, formal-language

The question's title says pretty much it.

What alternatives do we have to these classics?

> I look forward to talking with you.
>   I look forward to hearing from you.

**(without considering similar forms like I'm looking forward..)**

This questions arose in me when replying to an email which contains this phrase so I wanted **to reply with the same intention but without using the same words.**

Comment: -1.  You should tell us what you're trying to say; otherwise you may be given grammatically acceptable answers which may have connotations you would not wish your sentence to have. "looking forward to" may already be your best option.

Comment: @TRomano I've edited the question adding context and intention.

Comment: What do you understand this "intention" to be? What do you think "looking forward to" means in context? Try saying what it is that you want them to do. Do you want to know what the next step is? Are you looking for a way to ask them "What next"?

Comment: @TRomano The email contains information about and opening position so he's expecting me to reply. When replying him, my intention is also expecting him to reply, so I don't want to use the same words. Even if in this particular case it's not necessary to say it, but it could be, I want to know how to say it without sounding repetitive.
If someone says to you "I look forward to talking with you.
" is there any case when he/she doesn't imply that they are expecting my to reply?.

Comment: If there is no case where you would *not* be expecting a reply, then why go through the empty formality of saying that you hope to hear/look forward to hearing from the person. Instead you could close with something that advances your cause, such as  *I look forward to speaking with you.* There's no problem using some of the same words. You just want to move things forward.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm expecting to hear from you soon.
>   I'm expecting to have a talk with you soon.

Or

> I'm expecting to hear from you soon.
>   I'm expecting to have a talk with you soon.

I'd expect to see *look forward to* in formal contexts, rather than normal everyday conversation. And [I'm not the only one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3918/i-look-forward-or-im-looking-forward/3920#3920).

These sentences are usually email closings. See [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151980/what-informal-and-formal-letter-e-mail-closings-are-used-the-most) and [this](http://www.usingenglish.com/files/pdf/emails-opening-closing.pdf) or [this](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/conversational-email/) for more info on how to write an appropriate email closing.

---

***Footnote***: The original revision of OP had a grammar error. I move the correction down here.

Grammar polishing time!

> I look forward to *talk with you.
>   I look forward to *hear from you.

The structure "look forward to" is followed by a gerund. (Take a look at [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/28856/look-forward-to-meet-you-or-to-meeting-you/)) Also a Google search might bring up relevant results. I got [this tutorial](http://jakubmarian.com/i-am-looking-forward-to-hear-hearing-from-you/) as the first result. So, the correct forms of your sentences are

> I look forward to talk**ing** with you.
>   I look forward to hear**ing** from you.

Comment: I've edited my question, the bad grammar in my question was due to distraction. Thanks for the answer, but the grammar correction would be better located in a comment more than in an answer.

Comment: Ah, there are no strict guidelines to where the corrections belong. As I saw that the correction is highly relevant to the answer, I included it. I suggest you rollback to avoid reader confusions in the future.

Comment: @rewobs I edited my answer instead and moved the correction down. And no, more detailed and explained corrections (In your case the error falls into our Damkerng's category 2) are too long for comments. Anything else you might want to point out about my answer? I realize it might not have been as helpful as it intended to be.

Comment: Your answer was useful indeed, I just pointed out that the correction part could have been made in a comment , since it doesn't answer the question and there are other post on it. IMHO for the community it's better to have a clear and gramatically correct question and a clear answer to that question, than a more general answer which address a particular error in the writting of the question itself. Maybe I'm just wrong.